# Why does an unused FROM table make a statement slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have two tables. One changelog-table, the details of which aren't important here.
Another table that holds seller-information and most importantly has two columns:

- a primary ID
- and a id called ident (= the realworld ID).

When a seller is changed, a new entry is created, ident stays the same but the new entry get's a new ID.
I have a primary index on ID and another index on (ident,-id) so i can get the current data fast.

Per chance i found the following weird behaviour:

This takes veeery long to complete:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ident) sellers.* FROM changelog, sellers ORDER BY ident,id DESC;

                                  QUERY PLAN                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=741675.98..760122.47 rows=10 width=30)
   ->  Sort  (cost=741675.98..750899.22 rows=3689298 width=30)
         Sort Key: sellers.ident, sellers.id
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3.07..74457.37 rows=3689298 width=30)
               ->  Seq Scan on changelog  (cost=0.00..668.34 rows=38034 width=0)
               ->  Materialize  (cost=3.07..4.04 rows=97 width=30)
                     ->  Seq Scan on sellers  (cost=0.00..2.97 rows=97 width=30)
```

When i replace the DESC with -ID it's fast, but produces the same results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ident) sellers.* FROM changelog, sellers ORDER BY ident,-id;

                                         QUERY PLAN                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=706.37..92956.53 rows=10 width=30)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=706.37..83733.28 rows=3689298 width=30)
         ->  Index Scan using idx_sellers on sellers  (cost=0.00..17.70 rows=97 width=30)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=706.37..1086.71 rows=38034 width=0)
               ->  Seq Scan on changelog  (cost=0.00..668.34 rows=38034 width=0)
```

When i remove the "changelog" out of the FROM, ORDER BY -id and DESC give the same query-plan, again fast.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ident) sellers.* FROM sellers ORDER BY ident,id, DESC   

                             QUERY PLAN                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=6.17..6.66 rows=10 width=30)
   ->  Sort  (cost=6.17..6.41 rows=97 width=30)
         Sort Key: ident, id
         ->  Seq Scan on sellers  (cost=0.00..2.97 rows=97 width=30)
```

My questions:

- Why does including a unused table in the FROM affect the query at all?
- Why does ORDER BY ident,-id not use the same plan as ORDER BY ident,id DESC?

Edit: My real query has of course a WHERE clause to join the two tables.

Comment: The cartesian product is intentional?

Comment: No. My RDBMS-knowledge is rusty :(.

Comment: It is not rusty, it is absent, IMHO. Omitting a part of a WHERE clause or a JOIN ... ON condition is a daily sin for everybody using SQL, but blaming the optimiser for that (without checking ...) is in a different league, IMHO.

Comment: I have a where-clause in my application, i just played around with the indices I created 4 years ago, and stumbled across this. I probably should have added the clause to my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such thing as an unused table in a query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ident) sellers.* 
FROM changelog, sellers ORDER BY ident,id DESC
```

You orginal query was creating a cross-join (every record in changelog was being joined to every record in sellers) which is one reason why you should avoid using the implied join syntax that was replaced with explicit syntax 20 years ago.

Comment: Ok, and can you explain the other question about the ORDER BY as well?

Comment: Sorry no, you would have to ask someone more familar with the Postgres internals for that

Comment: So what would be the proper way to do this? I actually have a "where changelog.record = sellers.ident" in the real application. With the where clause it's fast.

Comment: @FabianZeindl: the proper way to do this is to use JOIN predicates rather than a comma-separated list of relations in the FROM clause.  This tends to force you to think about how each table is related to the others.